# Is there any case when "ptr1 - ptr2 > 0" would differ from "ptr1 > ptr2"?

Tags: c++, pointers

Assuming the two pointers of the same type point within the same array (or the same object) so that both subtraction of two pointers and comparison are valid... is there any case where

```
if(ptr1 - ptr2 > 0)
```

would behave differently from

```
if(ptr1 > ptr2)
```

or are they at all times equivalent?

Comment: Barry's answer picks up on an ambiguity in the question. You say, "Assuming X, so that Y", and Barry notes a case where X is true and Y is false. At risk of invalidating his answer, could you clarify whether you intend for the purpose of the question to assume Y, or merely to assume X and (incorrectly as it turns out) deduce Y? :-)

Comment: ... only there's another case where X ("point within same array") is true and Y ("subtraction is valid") is false, mentioned in the quote in Barry's answer but that he doesn't pick up on. This is that if your implementation will allocate an array of `char` larger than the max value of `ptrdiff_t`, which is permitted by the standard for reasons I do not fully comprehend, then comparison always works but in some cases subtraction overflows and is therefore undefined.

Comment: @SteveJessop I didn't know there was a difference for member variables. I guess there's no point to change the question because my guess is many people have no idea about that either.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yeah, I think that's the less interesting case - but I added that note at the end of my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, there is such a case where the two will **not** behave the same.

Pointer difference is *signed* [expr.add]:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined **signed** integral
>   type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as [`std::ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) in the `<cstddef>` header

but with two caveats:

> As
>   with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.
>
> Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
>   one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.

On the comparison side, we have [expr.rel]:

> — If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to
>   the element with the higher subscript compares greater.
>   — If one pointer points to an element of an array, or to a subobject thereof, and another pointer points
>   one past the last element of the array, the latter pointer compares greater.
>   — If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such
>   members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member compares greater provided the two
>   members have the same access control (Clause 11) and provided their class is not a union.

The last bullet point there gives us a difference. Consider:

```
struct A {
    int x, y;
}

A a;
int *px = &a.x, *py = &a.y
```

`px > py` is defined but `px - py > 0` is **undefined**.

There is also of course the integer overflow case, if you have an enormous array:

```
array[0] > array[PTRDIFF_MAX + 10]         // defined
array[0] - array[PTRDIFF_MAX + 10] > 0     // undefined
```

Outside of those two cases, if the two pointers point to the same array (or one-past-the-end), the two expressions are equivalent. If the two pointers point to different arrays, then both are undefined.

Comment: answer is also valid for C.

Comment: An implementation could legitimately guarantee that a 32-bit `ptrdiff_t` could compare two pointers within an object without overflow by rejecting any array declaration of 2GB or larger (or even 1GB for that matter) and having any `malloc` request of such a size return `null`, or a system with 32-bit pointers could use a 64-bit `ptrdiff_t`.  If `ptrdiff_t` isn't guaranteed large enough to hold any legitimate pointer difference, what is it for?

Comment: @supercat It's the type of the expression `p1 - p2`. That's what it's for. There's no guarantee that it's big enough - that's why there's a sentence about overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barry: Would anything in the standard prohibit a 64-bit system from using making `ptrdiff_t` equivalent to `int8_t`?  It would be a silly thing to do, of course, but if there is no requirement that `ptrdiff_t` be large enough to be useful, is there anything in the standard that would prohibit an implementation from doing such a silly thing?

Comment: @supercat The only requirement is "The type `ptrdiff_t` is an implementation-defined signed integer type that can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object", with the note that its integer conversion rank should be "no greater than that of `signed long int` unless a larger size is necessary to
contain all the possible values." So it's *technically* feasible for `ptrdiff_t` to be `int8_t`, but that would make for a very poor implementation indeed!

Comment: @Barry: If the system allows array-ish objects bigger than 2GB, what qualitative difference would there be between having `ptrdiff_t` being an `int32_t` versus an `int8_t`?  If `ptrdiff_t` has to be able to hold the difference between addresses, neither works; if it doesn't, either will work just as well.

Comment: @supercat It's "**implementation-defined**". Full stop.

Answer (score 3):

Constructs like `if(ptr1 - ptr2 > 0)` can be dangerous.

Recently, I ran into a problem, where I had two pointers to type `T`:

```
T* p1;
T* p2;
```

and

```
sizeof(T) = 16
```

Now, there was a bug: difference between `p1` and `p2` was smaller than 16. So `p1 - p2` gave 0, which caused a lot of errors!

Try [this sample](https://ideone.com/ncQbh0).

The best solution is to use either:

```
if(ptr1 > ptr2)
```

or:

```
ptrdiff_t diff = (ptrdiff_t)p2 - (ptrdiff_t)p1;

if(diff > 0)
{
}
```

So, basically, these two construct may or may not be equivalent (depending on sign of the difference), but sometimes they may not work in the same way.

Pointers arithmetic can be very error-prone.

Comment: I can't think of any non-undefined-behaviour way to run into this problem.

Comment: I see your point, however that sample contains undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Actually, this (integer division during pointer arithmetic) is likely the reason pointer subtraction between members of the same object is undefined behavior, while comparison is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32 bit system, you might be able to allocate an array of more than 2 GB, and have two pointers to the start and end of the array that are more than 2 GB apart.

In this case, (ptr1 > ptr2) would yield a result of true, while (ptr1 - ptr2 > 0) would be undefined behaviour if ptrdiff_t is a signed 32 bit integer.

(Now since people rarely do this, there is a tiny chance that ptr1 > ptr2 might give the wrong result because of a compiler bug. If you have two int* more than 2GB apart, ptr1 - ptr2 would be defined behaviour, because the correct result fits into a 32 bit signed number, but I wouldn't be surprised if a compiler got it wrong).

Comment: What makes you say that there is a tiny chance for a compiler bug with `ptr1 > ptr2`? Have you encountered such a bug? I would be very surprised if the magnitude of the difference had an effect on the observable behavior with `ptr1 > ptr2`: the machine instructions that are generated by this expression should work for the entire value range of any pointer.

Answer (score -3):

It depends how you are doing the subtraction between ptr1 and ptr2. If it is signed then it should work fine otherwise if it is unsigned the result could be different. For example when:

```
if (ptr1 > ptr2)
```

will fail and subtraction:

```
ptr1 - ptr2
```

is unsigned the result of subtraction will be positive, hence the:

```
if (ptr1 - ptr2 > 0)
```

will be true.

I would recommend using the ptr1 > ptr2 because it is less prone to mistakes and pitfalls.